# jQuery: Simultaneously fadeIn + fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm designing a small portfolio website for my friend and I am having difficulty trying to get the fadeIn + fadeOut effect to work properly. The images are sliding + fading, however, there is a long delay in between the fades and you can momentarily see the background. The slider I am using is based off of the following tutorial:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/

The only changes I have done to the original code is to add a caption to the images and (trying to add) a fade effect when the images slide.

**Javascript**

```
$(".image_reel").fadeIn(500).delay(0).fadeOut(500);
    $(".image_reel").animate({
        left: -image_reelPosition
    }, 500);
    $(".image_reel").delay(0).fadeIn(500);
```

*The code here can be found in the `rotate` function on the tutorial website.*

So, as I stated above the code here is successfully fading and sliding the images, however, there is a delay where you can momentarily see the background.

Any help would greatly be appreciating as to how I can get one image to fade out while the other image is fading in **at the same time**.

Comment: Could you post a link to your current version? I can't work out from the description what you're trying to achieve or what you're seeing.

Comment: @peter
`http://fabioschicken.com/ap`
This link shows you what is occurring when the images fade/slide.

`http://fabioschicken.com/ap/js/carousel.js`
This links you to the source code for the slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i've done in the past is have two div's that overlap, and alternate fadein/fadeout, dynamically loading the next image in the div that is currently invisible.

Here is the code i used to accomplish it:

```
var FeatureRotator = (function($,global) {
    var self = {},
        currentFeature = 0,
        images = [],
        imageData = [],
        imagePrefix = "/images/",
        timer = null,        
        totalImages = 0,
        initialFeature = 0,
        interval,
        blendSpeed;


    function setVisibleImage(iid) {
        $("#img1").attr('src',images[iid].src).css('opacity',1);
        $("#img2").css('opacity',0);
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $("#f"+iid).addClass("active");
    }

    function setCurrentImage(id) {
        currentFeature = id;
        setVisibleImage(id);
    }

    function doHoverIn(obj) {
        var position = global.parseInt(obj.target.attributes.position.value,10);

        if (currentFeature === position) {
            self.pause();
        } else {
            setCurrentImage(global.parseInt(position, 10));
            self.pause();
        }
    }

    function doHoverOut() {
        self.unpause();
    }

    self.init = function(options,callback) {
        var i = 0,
            tempImg = null,
            element = null,
            img1 = null,
            img2 = null;

        interval = options.interval || 5000;
        blendSpeed = options.blendSpeed || 500;
        element = options.element;
        initialFeature = options.initialFeature || 0;
        imagePrefix = options.imagePrefix;
        imageData = options.imageData || [];
        img1 = $("<img/>").attr('id','img1').css('cursor','pointer');
        img2 = $("<img/>").attr('id','img2').css('cursor','pointer').css('opacity','0').css('margin-top',-options.height);
        img1.click(function() {
            window.location = imageData[currentFeature].link;
        });
        img2.click(function() {
            window.location = imageData[currentFeature].link;
        });
        $(element).append(img1).append(img2);

        totalImages = imageData.length; //2;//$(".feature").size();

        for (i = 0;i < totalImages; i++) {
            tempImg = new global.Image();
            tempImg.src = imagePrefix + imageData[i].image;            //"feature_" + i + ".png";
            images.push(tempImg);


            $("#f"+i).css('background-image','url("'+imagePrefix+"feature_"+i+"_thumb.png"+'")')
                     .hover(doHoverIn, doHoverOut)
                     .attr('position',i);
        }

        setVisibleImage(initialFeature);

        if (options.autoStart) {
            self.start();
        }
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    };

    function updateImage() {        
        var active = global.parseInt($("#img1").css('opacity'),10) === 1 ? "#img1" : "#img2",
            nextFeature = (currentFeature === totalImages-1 ? 0 : currentFeature+1);

        if (active === "#img1") {
            $("#img2").attr('src',images[nextFeature].src);

            $("#img2").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 1);            
            $("#img1").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 0);
        } else {
            $("#img1").attr('src',images[nextFeature].src);            
            $("#img1").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 1);            
            $("#img2").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 0);
        }

        $("#f"+currentFeature).removeClass("active");
        $("#f"+nextFeature).addClass("active");

        currentFeature = nextFeature;
    }



    self.start = function() {
        currentFeature = initialFeature;
        setVisibleImage(currentFeature);
        timer = global.setInterval(function(){
            updateImage();
        }, interval);
    };

    self.stop = function() {
        global.clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    self.pause = function() {
        global.clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    self.unpause = function() {
        timer = global.setInterval(function(){
            updateImage();
        }, interval);
    };


    return self;
}(this.jQuery, this));
```

Note that there is a bit more required to make this work as is. The main part of interest to you would be updateImage()

Comment: Thanks Jason, it works well!  Here's the code I used to used to try FeatureRotator: http://jsfiddle.net/fNHUq/4/

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution I can think of is to wrap the `image` in a `span`, `fadeIn` the `image` itself, and then `fadeOut` the `span`.

The element "flashing" briefly before or after the effect is something I've seen happen before, and it usually only affects certain browsers and is related to the JavaScript implementations.  Make sure you are using the newest version of jQuery to ameliorate crossbrowser effects.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to actually do any sliding: just fades. So I think that the way to get the effect you want is to have two images visible at a time.

Suppose you're currently showing image 1 and you want to fade to image 2. You give image 1 `z-index: 0`; you give image 2 `z-index: 1` and fade it in. In the callback at the end of the fade you set image 1 to `display:none` or `opacity: 0` and you can reset image 2's `z-index` to 0.

The tricky bit will be working out what to do about the current fade if the user is clicking the buttons very fast. Given how fast the fades are you might want to keep a single transition pending and finish the first one before doing the last one.